# Compaction of big Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka

We have kafka compaction enabled and it works great except for one topic which is big (over 30M of records and over 40GB in size). Are there any limitations/configuration for kafka topic compaction?

Thanks,
Gediminas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the solution. We used Kafka 0.9 which had a bug. When getting topic size, it used integer variables. So all topics over 2Gb were failing because of it. Later Kafka has this fix https://github.com/apache/kafka/commit/1f64942021bd8fe0f2791700fb402cfac1acc9de#diff-d7330411812d23e8a34889bee42fedfe
After the upgrade, our problem is solved.